# Django - Product Details in XML file

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a task to export all product details such as name, price etc. from db to XML file. Since now i'm exporting most of the fields and save them to an XML file. However i'm a bit confused on how to export images.
I have 2 models one for Product and one for ProductImages, see below:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, null=True, unique=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Also according to requirements there are two fields where images should be exported. If there is one image (product table) should be exported to `item_image_link` which i exporting it with no problem. And if there are more than one (ProductImage table) to `item_additional_image_link` and here is where i have issue.

I iterate over products table like below and then trying to find all images for specific product id like:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(product_status=True)
images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product__id__in=products)

for products in products:
  item = ET.SubElement(channel, "item")
  g_item_id = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}id")).text = products.sku
  g_item_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}image_link")).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+products.image.url
  for image in images:
    g_item_additional_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}additional_image_link")).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+image.image.url
```

However the g_item_additional_image_link brings all images i have in db for all products. I suppose the problem is in the `images query`. How can i show images related to each product?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define an extra query for the images as django links them for you.
First, add a [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to the products query. That way django does not create a second query when ietrating over images:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(product_status=True).prefetch_related('images')
```

And then, just iterate over the related images:

```
for image in product.images.all():
...
```

You also should use `product` instead of `products` when iterating over them.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(product_status=True).prefetch_related('images')

for product in products:
    item = ET.SubElement(channel, "item")
    g_item_id = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}id")).text = product.sku
    g_item_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}image_link")).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+products.image.url
    for image in product.images.all():
        g_item_additional_image_link = ET.SubElement(item, ("{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}additional_image_link")).text = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'+image.image.url
```

Comment: Thank you for help! I modified as you proposed above but i get `TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`. Any ideas?

Comment: I added `for image in product.images.all()`and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad. Will adapt the answer.

Comment: BTW i do not know if it is right to ask it in the same q? But if i want to show results on the same line separated by comma, how can i do that? Thank you!

Comment: Where do you wanna show this? Inside your XML output? Maybe you better open a new specific question for this.

Comment: Yes, inside the XML file. OK, np.